# JSF 2.0: <f:viewParam> and default converters

Tags: java, jsf, datetime, jsf-2, converters

I would like to use a standard JSF converter (`javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter`) for a view parameter

From the documentation:

> You can refer to the converter by class or by its ID using the
>   component tag's converter attribute. The ID is defined in the
>   application configuration resource file

I then tried:

```
<f:viewParam
    name        = "rangeStartCreationDate"
    value       = "#{doiListController.model.rangeStartCreationDate}"
    converter   = "javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter"
/>
```

but I get

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter not found.
```

I then tried the second option (by ID). I defined the converter in `faces-config.xml`

```
<converter> 
    <converter-id>DateTimeConverter</converter-id> 
    <converter-class>javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter</converter-class> 
</converter>
```

and used the ID

```
<f:viewParam
    name        = "rangeStartCreationDate"
    value       = "#{doiListController.model.rangeStartCreationDate}"
    converterId = "DateTimeConverter"
/>
```

In this case I get

```
Conversion Error setting value 'Tue Jul 24 00:00:00 CEST 2012' for 'null Converter'.
```

Is there a way to let JSF instantiate the converter or to I have to instantiate it manually (in some bean)?

Comment: The converter id is javax.faces.DateTime, so try `converter="javax.faces.DateTime"`

Comment: @Adam Thanks it works! Post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The converter id is `javax.faces.DateTime`, so try

```
<f:viewParam
  converter="javax.faces.DateTime"
... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use f:convertDateTime with ISO pattern

```
<f:viewParam name="rangeStartCreationDate" value="#{doiListController.model.rangeStartCreationDate}" >
    <f:convertDateTime type="localDate" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
</f:viewParam>
```