# <p:calendar Conversion Error Setting Value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar, converters

I have two calendars, one for start date and one for end date. When I click the commandButton to trigger method `updateAccount` I am receiving error message:

```
Conversion Error setting value 'Tue Feb 26 16:41:43 EST 2013' for 'null Converter'.Conversion Error setting value 'Tue Feb 26 16:41:43 EST 2013' for 'null Converter'.
Conversion Error setting value 'Tue Feb 25 16:41:43 EST 2014' for 'null Converter'.Conversion Error setting value 'Tue Feb 25 16:41:43 EST 2014' for 'null Converter'.
```

The commandButton should reload the page with the values from the selectmenu and calendars as parameters for SQL queries. The value assigned to the calendar is of type Date. Is this error being caused because the output from the calendar is of type String and trying to be assigned to variable of type Date? From examples I've found on-line  didn't require a converter. Is that incorrect? If so, how do I solve this error message.

My JSF page:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="account" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.account}" />   
    <f:viewParam name="start" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.start}" />   
    <f:viewParam name="end" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.end}" />       
    <f:viewAction action="#{accountAnalysisBean.pullData}" /> 
</f:metadata>

<h:form>
    <p:panelGrid columns="6">
    <f:facet name="header"> 
    <p:selectOneMenu id="pickAccount" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.pickAccount}" required="true" >      
   <f:selectItems value="#{editAccountBean.allAccounts}" />                                 
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputLabel value="Start Date: " />
        <p:calendar id="start" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.start}"  pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" navigator="true" />   
        <h:outputLabel value="End Date: " />
        <p:calendar id="end" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.end}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" navigator="true" />
        <p:commandButton value="Get Account" action="#{accountAnalysisBean.updateAccount}" > 
            <f:param name="start" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.start}"/>
            <f:param name="end" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.end}"/>    
            <f:param name="account" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.id}"/>
        </p:commandButton>
        </f:facet>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

My Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AccountAnalysisBean {

private String account = "";
private String id = "";
private String pickAccount = "";
private Date start;
private Date end;

//gettters and setters

public void pullData() {

    if (account != "") {

        //pull various fields from database given account value
    } else {    
        //set default null values
    }
}

public void updateAccount() {

fix = DAOFactory.getInstance("fix_site2.jdbc");
datalist = fix.getMyDataDAO();
id = datalist.findAccountID(pickAccount); //returns an ID from a DB given account selected from menu

ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/AccountAnalysis.xhtml?account=" + id + 
                "&start=" + start + "&end=" + end + "&includeViewParams=true");
}

//remained of code omitted for clarity

}
```

I am using JSF 2.2 and Primefaces 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using

```
<f:viewParam name="start" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.start}" />   
<f:viewParam name="end" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.end}" />
```

and those properties are `Date` objects, while request params are `String`s so you need a converter.

```
<f:viewParam name="start" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.start}" converter="javax.faces.DateTime">
```

should work.

credit: [JSF 2.0: `<f:viewParam>` and default converters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11628169/2911357)

Comment: Thank you Michele. That solved that error message however I now receive `j_idt2: 'Wed Feb 27 09:11:55 EST 2013' could not be understood as a date.` Do I need to do something else? The default values on the initial page load are `private Date start = new DateTime().minusMonths(12).toDate();`. I receive this error after clicking the commandButton.

Comment: @Steve - you still need to specify a format for the converter, given that the default format is "MON dd, YYYY". Use the `<f:dateTimeConverter/>` notation instead, so you can define the format

Comment: @kolossus I would add if inside the <f:viewParam> component as such `<f:viewParam name="start" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.start}"><f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" /></f:viewParam>`? I am receiving the same error when I do that.

Comment: @Steve - you're supposed to match the pattern to the pattern of the argument you're receiving. So in your case, try `EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy`